# How to auto postback with Select2 using MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I am trying to use Select2.js within my MVC 6 (Core) project, where if a user selects a value (or multiple values) within the first listbox, then they are then provided with an updated list of values within the second listbox. So for example... if a user selects "Ford" and "Renault" from the Manufacturer listbox, then they are only provided with relevant values in the Brand listbox e.g. Mondeo, Mustang, Clio, Megane etc.

**My View syntax is:**

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ManufacturerID').select2({
            placeholder: 'Please make a selection...',
            width: 500
        });
        $('#BrandID').select2({
            placeholder: 'Please make a selection...',
            width: 500
        });
    });
</script>

<form asp-action="Generation">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ManufacturerID, Model.ManufacturerNames)
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.BrandID, Model.BrandNames)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If I click the submit button, the post action method successfully acquires a list of Manufacturer ID's:

```
// POST: MyController/Generation
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Generation(MyViewModel myViewModel, IEnumerable<int> manufacturerID) 
{
    return RedirectToAction("Generation");
}
```

But what I really want is something similar to AJAX Update Panel in Web Forms where the call to the controllers post action method is performed immediately on selecting an option from the listbox, not when the user clicks submit.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
X22

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  pageInit();
});

function pageInit(){
  $('#ManufacturerNames').off();
  $('#ManufacturerNames').on('change', function(e){
    //ajax request here
    //call pageInit() in your callback to reattach select2
    //and event handler if you are fully replacing the dropdown.
  });

  $('#BrandNames').off();
  $('#BrandNames').on('change', function(e){
    //ajax request here
    //same as callback above depending on how you go about doing this.
  });
}
```

This is the manual way but since you are using a library like select2, they may provide an easy way to set this up in your initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sure what the off() method is doing, but nevertheless it is causing the code to behave incorrectly. If you could perhaps explain a bit further with an example of an "Ajax request" and also how to perform the "call pageInit() in your callback", that would be greatly appreciated.